# Dynamically changing the style of an Angular component using different CSS style sheets

Tags: css, angular, dynamic, styles

I am trying to get a dynamic style-sheet change for a singlepage-application to work in Angular. The idea is to create different themes and let the users choose from them in a dedicated menu. There may be many themes, so nevermind that the example below only has two variants. The functionality is ready. As of now, I have collected all styles in single large scss-files, one for each theme. (Note that I am well aware that in Angular you often split the styles in many sub-scss files, for each component. But for this idea to work, I wanted to have it all in single files for each theme). I have the menu working, and use localstorage for the app to remember which theme has been chosen, since the site has to be reloaded for the changes to take effect.

Now for the problem:
In app.component.ts, the style sheet is defined, in standard form (i.e. styleUrls: [filename]). When using a static file path/name there, and when using a variable, defined just outside the @component-code, the styles works perfectly. But for the dynamic theme change, I have a simple fetch of the variable from localstorage:

```
var settingsString = localStorage.getItem('usergraphicsdata');
if (isDefined(settingsString)) {
  let myUserSettings = JSON.parse(settingsString);
  const themename = myUserSettings.theme;
```

It all works there too. Different console.logs confirms it understands everything it should. But then comes the problem.

```
if(themename == "theme1"){
    var stylePath = "./app.component_theme1.scss";
    var graphicFolder = '/assets/theme1/';
    } else if(themename == "theme2"){
    var stylePath = "./app.component_theme2.scss";
    var graphicFolder = '/assets/theme2/';
    }
  }
```

Then comes the @component with its styleUrls: [stylePath]

For some reason the if-conditions are not regarded, and the result is always that the theme declared first (in the above case "theme1") will be active. So if I just change the order in the condition, and put the code for theme 2 first, that will be chosen for the site, disregarding which theme variable is actually fetched from localstorage

I have tried several other variants as well, but this one seems to be closest to a solution. Could it be an issue with Angular limiting style changes in runtime contra build? Or have I forgotten something basic in the if-condition?

Best regards and sorry for my limited english.
Per

Comment: Have you tried the ngClass and ngStyle approach? https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-ngclass-and-ngstyle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215977/angular-ngstyle, https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/, https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description

Comment: Yes, in several tags where these solutions fit. But for the whole site to change theme, they would be clumsy tools, I figure. I would have to setup huge amounts of ngclass and ngsyle conditions in most tags in the site. There may be dozens of themes with different syle sheets and image folders. ngsyle/ngclass seems useful for only limited changes where there are just two alternatives.

Comment: The approach you're trying to develop feels very on-Angular. I don't know whether it is possible or not, but I always had the impression that what is in the @Component-decorator is unchangeable. It's that part of a component-type that needs to be defined and consequently is readonly. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you solve it with routing? Duplicate the component for each theme, just with a different css-file but use for all those components the same html-file and put in the menu a link to that component (with a specific theme). The added value would be that the theme name also appears in the url and you can easily apply different logic without things getting to be convoluted (different typescript-files).

Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sunflower',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sunflower.component.scss']
})
export class SunflowerComponent {

@Component({
  selector: 'roses',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roses.component.scss']
})
export class RosesComponent {
```

If you tried it, please share the problems you've encountered.

**update**

I made an extremely basic demo (that I've tested), you can find it here:

[repo](https://github.com/qqtf/flowers)

Take care & good luck.

Comment: maybe different selector names will cause an error, probably not if you don't use them and maybe you need to work with <router-outlet>

Comment: Thanks qqtf.  I tried your suggestion, but without immediate success. Firstly, it seems I can't put the export inside the if-conditions. Angular gave me red text:
"Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"

Secondly it looks as if I have to do a lot of work in other components if I name the exported classes differently. As of now, I find 16 places across the app where I have to build checks for which theme-name is sent out from app.component. 

I will mess around a little more with this approach, though. If I get any further, I will share it.

/Per

Comment: Of course you'll get that error. You need to generate a new component for each 'theme' (which I gave a flower name), meaning a separate file, which can have only one list of import statements on top. Copy-paste obviously will not work. You will also need to add a router-module in which you define the paths for each theme: 'sunflower', 'roses', which you need to build up your routerlink-definition in the <a>-tag that you will use in each menu-item. Every time you'll click a new menu-item, you'll call a new component, which will work with the same html-template but a different css-one.

Comment: added example repo to answer

Comment: Thanks again qqtf. I'm not an Angular pro, its quite unintutitve to me, so I'm sorry for not understanding your tips. I'll try it later, but I may have come across a possible reason why my if:s dont' work:

As I mentioned, it looks rigt in the console reply from my ifs, but the style is not changed. Now I read about possible bug issues regarding ViewEncapsulation.None, and that the styles, once loaded, is never removed. Possibly by design. That would explain my problem. Reading on about "Lazy loading", there is a page out there, wich addresses it: "Dynamically Load CSS with the Angular CLI"

Comment: You're working in the wrong direction. If you can define a .css-style on higher level, you should. Meaning a shared .css -sheet for the whole application, where you might also import external libraries like bootstrap. And so further down: a css-style sheet per component/module, and the final hail-mary-pass would be something like ViewEncapsulation.None. The lazy loading is an issue that comes with loading a lot of data and wanting to prevent that your app only starts working, when download is complete. Like a set of pictures in a carousel. For .css-files, they need to be extremely heavy. (...)

Comment: That's why, in the example cited, they are literally loading a css-library in that stylesheet. As you haven't mentioned that this was the case ... you're heading in the wrong direction. Lazy loading is not the issue. Your issue is not that it would take TO LONG to get from one syle to another. Your issue is GETTING THERE.

Comment: Thumbs up for that explanation. I will try your example. I'll get back as soon as I can.

Comment: I've tried your solution qqtf. Principally it works, since it lets me easily steer the site towards either css filepath. So your solution is valid. However, my site is a bit complex, with large amounts of intertwined data from both the server, external API:s, from localstorage and from IndexedDB. They require a coded string in the address field, and I struggle with collisions between the routed path that change with each skin, and the datastring. It leads to minutes of reloading all data with each theme change. Maybe possible to get around. But I still cant understand why my ifs dont work.

Comment: The answer on that last question stands in the '@angular/core' library, lines 700 and following. Because you can't dynamically (re)resolve a component in the NgModule. Once a component is instantiated, it needs to be resolved @ the NgModule, with whatever property-values it has at that moment. You can dynamically create component instances, you can't dynamically edit them. Once you created an instance, wanting to change a property of it (like you want), would imply that you need to destroy the instance first, recreate it and reregister it with NgModule. That's how I INTERPRETED the library.

Comment: every time you route, you do restart your lifecycle. Unless you only change query params (so 35618463, 41678356, 39533291). Maybe if you define an observable on queryparams, define css-elements based on that, with two-way binding? The url for your spa-application and the api-calls should normally not be interlinked (you can separate them), and even if not, you should be able to chop off those query-parameters again where necessary. Just an idea, maybe/probably not a good one. Take care & good luck.